# simplify a boolean expression Q = (a' + b')' + a.b'

Tags: boolean-logic

How can simplify down the following boolean expression ?

[image: my expression]

Comment: Have you attempted simplifying it yourself at all?

Comment: @Dukeling I got as far as a+b+a.b'

Comment: That's your misstep, the symbol changes - `(c+d)'` goes to `c'.d'` - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think from the first DeMorgan law you can convert it to:

```
Q = A.B + A.B'
```

Which is A.

Answer (score 1):

This could be written as

```
Q = A * B + A * B'
```

that is like to write

```
Q = A * (B + B')
```

that is

```
Q = A * 1 => A
```